# How to change the order of type application parameters for a constructor

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt, existential-type

I've got the following data type definition:

```
type DynamicF' :: k -> (k -> Type) -> Type
data DynamicF' k f where
  DynamicF :: Typeable a => f a -> DynamicF' k f
```

The thing is, generally, I'm going to be specialising `k` to `Type`. So I've provided the following type alias:

```
type DynamicF f = DynamicF' Type f
```

Then I can do things like this:

```
data Showable a where
  Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable a

f :: DynamicF Showable -> String
f (DynamicF @_ @a x) = g x where
  g :: Showable a -> String
  g (Showable y) = show y
```

This is perhaps a silly example but hopefully illustrative, but notice the pattern match:

```
DynamicF @_ @a x
```

And in particular, the underscore required for the first argument.

This is because the first type application argument seems to be against `f`, not `a`, in the `DynamicF` constructor.

Apparently I can change the order of these using `forall blah.`, and perhaps using `forall {blah}.` like constructs.

But I'm not sure where to actually put the `forall.`s in this code so they I can instead just do:

```
f (DynamicF @a x)
```

in the pattern match, instead of requiring the silly underscore.

Comment: The way you have it here works just fine for me - I can `DynamicF @a x`, and it takes the correct `a`. It works because in the type signature of `DynamicF` variable `a` comes first, so it's first in the pattern match too.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to use "visible dependent quantification" (`forall->`): `type DynamicF' :: forall k -> (k -> Type) -> Type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right place to put the `forall` is in the `data` declaration:

```
type DynamicF' :: k -> (k -> Type) -> Type
data DynamicF' k f where
  DynamicF :: forall a f k. Typeable a => f a -> DynamicF' k f
```

If you were concerned that somehow the `f` and `k` couldn't be specified in a `forall` because they are part of the `DynamicF' k f` type, don't be.  It is the type of the "result" of the constructor that determines what variables become part of the final type.  For example, the following declaration works exactly like your original:

```
data DynamicF' doesn't match where
  DynamicF :: forall whatever you want. 
              Typeable whatever => you whatever -> DynamicF' want you
```

However, note that I wasn't able to duplicate your issue.  The order was already `forall a f k` for this constructor (because the `Typeable a =>` puts `a` in first position).

Comment: Strange you couldn't replicate this. Perhaps I'm dealing with a GHC version specific quirk. This behaviour is on 9.2.2. Anyway I guess I'll revisit this after an upgrade.